# Homebrew is showing no such file or directory while executing python code, after updating python 3.8 from 3.11

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew

I am trying to run some test cases in python, I had some system requirements and I had change my python version from 3.11 to 3.8, So I have installed new version with `brew install python@3.8` and I can see my version.

But when I am trying to run the code it is throwing below error.

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pyenv/2.3.29/libexec/pyenv-exec: /opt/homebrew/bin/pipenv: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3.10: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/pyenv/2.3.29/libexec/pyenv-exec: line 48: /opt/homebrew/bin/pipenv: Undefined error: 0
```

First of all I don't know why it is showing 3.10 it was not there at all in my system.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you were using `pyenv` and you have pulled the rug from underneath it. If you are using `pyenv` already anyway, just ask it to install additional versions as you need them; read its documentation for details. In the meantime, probably restore 3.10 in Brew and take it from there.